# Python3 How to check if an item is already in txt file

Tags: python

The code below takes a list as an input and appends each item in a TXT file. 
Nonetheless, I cannot figure out **how to check if an item of the list is already in this TXT file** so that I can omit it instead of appending it again.

```py
with open(path2, 'a') as f:
    for item in mylist:
        f.write(item+'\n')
```

Comment: Read about the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) object in the docs.

Comment: Research this: "How to read a txt file?".

Answer (score 0):

You can do a read before write to check if the file already has it. Don't forget to set the read again at the beginning with `seek`

```
my_list =['HI',
         'This',
         'IS',
         'A',
         'TEST',
         'HI',
         'CONTINUE',
         'IS']
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.seek(0)
        if item not in f.read():
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

This writes the below in file:

```
HI
This
IS
A
TEST
CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 0):

As Keith has commented in reply to your question, a Set object would be useful here, as one method.

```py
x = set()

with open("filename.txt", 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil.readlines():
        x.add(line.strip()) # Remove newline character and other whitespace chars from the end

for item in yourlist:
    x.add(str(item))

with open("filename.txt", 'w') as fil: # opening with 'w' will overwrite the file
    for set_item in x:
        fil.write(set_item + '\n')
```

Of course this will re-write the whole file which may take some time with lots of lines present, and there are different solutions as well, this is just one of them.

Another solution is the read all the contents of the file and save them to a second list, then compare your input list to the file output list and write every list item that isn't in the file

```py
fil_list = []
with open("filename.txt", 'r') as fil:
    for line in fil.readlines():
        fil_list.append(line.strip())

with open("filename.txt", 'a') as fil:
    for item in your_list:
        if not (item in fil_list):
            fil.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

Naturally, omit '\n' and str() function in case your list items are already strings, and if they contain a newline character already. You get the idea.